# How to insert rows to table in a loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following `plpgsql` function in `PostgreSQL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1()
  RETURNS SETOF type_a AS
$BODY$
declare
    param text;
    sqls varchar;
    row type_a;
begin
     code.....

    sqls='select * from func3(' || param || ') ';
    for row in execute sqls LOOP
        return next row;
    END LOOP;
    end if;
    return;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I want to add an `insert` statment into the loop, so that the loop will work as it is now but also all rows will be saved in a table.

```
for row in execute sqls LOOP
INSERT INTO TABLE new_tab(id, name)
return next row;
```

the thing is that I don't know how to do that... the insert statment normaly has syntax of:

```
INSERT INTO new_tab(id, name)
SELECT x.id, x.name
FROM y
```

but this syntax doesn't fit here. There is no query to select rows from.... the rows are in the loop.

Comment: It has also other syntax where you provide values, see - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: It the same thing. for using the `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
 VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);` you need to specify `value1,value2,value3,...` i don't see how can I access thouse values...

Comment: No need for a function or a loop, just use: `insert into new_tab (id, name) select * from func3(..)` Or do you want your `func1()` to insert the rows **and** return them at the same time?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  note that its dynamic query... how would u write it without loop?

Answer (score 1):

Basic insert with values looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Based on the additional comments you need to use cursor instead of `execute sqls`.

Comment: Can you explain how do I get the values? I don't know what the values are.

Comment: what field are you planning to insert into? do you have definition of the destination table?

Comment: table has same fields as  TYPE type_a

Comment: I have updated the answer with cursor based solution.

Comment: That syntax (in the second part of your answer) is invalid for Postgres.

Comment: yes, just noticed that is psql. anyway using cursor in psql will be similar.

Comment: No need for a cursor in Postgres. (btw: `psql` is the command line client, the DBMS' name is either PG, Postgres or PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop, you can use `insert .. select ... returning` in dynamic SQL just as well:

```
create or replace function func1()
  returns table (id integer, name text)
as
$$
declare 
  param text;
begin
  param := ... ;
  return query execute 
      'insert into new_tab (id, name)
       select id, name
       from func3($1)
       returning *'
    using param; 
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Note that I used a parameter placeholder and the `USING` clause instead of concatenating the parameter into the query - much more robust.

Comment: what return table means?

Comment: It means the function returns a set of rows ("a table"). It's essentially the same as `RETURNS SETOF type_a` but you don't have to create a type for that first. See the manual for details. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: Ok nice. can I use this method if I just want to insert to table ? meaning changing it to returns void?